# How to set the jdbc ClientInfo in a MySQL DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In Java with MySQL we want to add the jdbc ClientInfo to identify the source of each query. Currently we can do something like:

```
    try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()){
        connection.setClientInfo("ApplicationName", "MyApp");
    }
```

But I need to add it to every connection created and means checking all the source code for places where a new connection is created. I will like to set it to the DataSource level.

So far what works for me is to extends the DataSource with a custom overriden getConnection method that calls setClientInfo. This is not only a dirty workarround but datasource specific.

I have seen that mysql driver has [ClientInfoProviders](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-api/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/ClientInfoProvider.java) like the default [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CommentClientInfoProvider](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/CommentClientInfoProvider.java). A custom ClientInfoProvider can be configured like:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(PropertyKey.clientInfoProvider.getKeyName(), "foo.bar.CustomClientInfoProvider");
    properties.setProperty(APPLICATION_NAME, "MyApp");

    HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setDataSourceProperties(properties);
    ...
```

But it is only called if someone calls the getClientInfo in the connection anyway.

So I will like to know:

- Is there support in the MySql driver to set the clientInfo in the DataSource just by setting properties?
- If there is a way. How can it be done?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  I hope that you find it better now. Please, provided any feedback as you seem to have experience with java jdbc drivers

Comment: It looks better now. My experience with the MySQL Connector/J driver is limited, but looking at [MySQL Connector/J documentation, Configuration Properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), I'd suggest trying the connection property `connectionAttributes` or maybe `sessionVariables` (although I'm not sure if that is actually related to how MySQL Connector/J handles client info!)

Comment: Maybe if you use another sql or javadb which is availabe in compilers of java can be better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use AspectJ as a possible solution for it. You can create an aspect which will intercept calls of the `DataSource.getConnection` method and then call the `setClientInfo` method with configured parameters when the connection is established.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Ilya Lysenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61014951), I have used this aspect in my Spring Boot application, this aspect get invoked every time when database connection is returned from `getConnection` method, then using this aspect I am setting `client info` in connection object.

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class ConnectionAspect {
    
    public ConnectionAspect() {
    }

    @AfterReturning(
        pointcut = "execution(* *..*getConnection(..))",
        returning = "connection"
    )
    public void afterReturningConnection(JoinPoint joinPoint, Connection connection) throws SQLClientInfoException {
        LOGGER.debug("Connection Aspect triggered.");
            connection.setClientInfo("OCSID.CLIENTID", "JAY");
        }

    }
}
```